# сменила пароль root в phpmyadmin: никак не могу зайти

Tags: phpmyadmin, xampp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не появляется даже сама страница авторизации...
Как исправить ситуацию?помогите...

Answer (score 2):

В папке `xampp/myadmin` открыла файл `config.inc.php` и в этой строке, в пустом месте ' ' поставила пароль:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Всё заработало.

Comment: хотя может это и ошибочное решение проблемы было